# SVN server for network

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, svn

I'm struggling to get my svnserver working as I need it to. What I'm trying to do is to set the server up on one of my VMs so that it would be visible for my hostOS and other VMs. What I have currently done is:

1. Downloaded and installed VisualSVN server
2. Configured bridged adapters on my VMs (so it looks like a true network)
3. Created repos/users.

I still can use svn only in the VM that the server is installed on. Is there any way to make it global? Or is the VisualSVN server a wrong choice for that? I can use anything.

Comment: How many users? How many repos?

Comment: I created two users, two repos. But does it make a difference? I can't reach the svnserver from other VM or even from hostOS.

Comment: I am assuming a lot here, but if you are using VirtualBox for a vm, and your SVNServer is on Window 2008+ SERVER then you might have a firewall issue. Bridged network on Oracle's vm works for me across several server/workstations/OS variations too, but the Win server ports are closed by default save the ones opened by Server Manager. The plot deepens.. some software from MS or other vendors have requirements to first have a PDC, use domain-only authentication, require MS-SQL server - read the full installation manual.